# How does Elinks render HTML?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, elinks

I like the [`elinks` browser](http://elinks.or.cz/) and I would like to know how does it render the HTML into text, using ANSI styles.

I suppose there is a library behind `elinks` to handle the rendering, or there should be. Is it possible to use that library in another project (e.g. to create a bridge to NodeJS)?

I would like to know where to start. `:-)`

Comment: Have you had a look at the `elinks` source code?

Comment: @Celada Yes! But I am not a C/C++ guru... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a brief look at the source code.  The HTML parsing and rendering code is a core part of elinks, and while it appears to be somewhat modular, it is not a separate library.  It might be possible to separate it, but not without a good deal of work.

If you're curious, the `src/README` file provides an overview of how the various parts depend on each other.  The HTML parsing and rendering code is under `src/document/`, but also depends on `src/viewer/`, `src/config/`, and other parts of the code.

But to start, see if you can get `elinks -dump` to do what you want.  Good UNIX tools are designed to work together with other tools, and this is how elinks provides its rendering service without being an interactive browser.  You will probably want to use a custom config file to control how you want the dump to look.  Take a look at [`man 5 elinks.conf`](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manpages/elinks.conf.5.html), in the `document.dump` section... and of course [`man elinks`](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manpages/elinks.1.html) to read up on the `-dump` and `-config-file` options.